# Wordpress: Why did my child theme not carry some CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using a child theme to modify the Twenty Thirteen theme. However, when I activated it some of the CSS seems to have reverted back to the year 2000. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xI6bw.jpg) for reference. Why did this happen? My style sheet for the child theme is pretty blank...Note - I removed the other parts of the comment that I've read are unnecessary, such as description and whatnot.

```
/*Theme Name:   Twenty Thirteen Child

 Template:     twentythirteen
 **/


<style>


#fd_question_submit_button {
    position:absolute;

}

</style>
```

**Inspect element on Chrome**

```
element.style {
}
localhost/media="all"
#fd_question_submit_button {
    position: absolute;
}
localhost/media="all"
#anspress *, #anspress *:before, #anspress *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheetinput:not([type="image" i]), textarea {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheetinput[type="button" i], input[type="submit" i], input[type="reset" i], input[type="file" i]::-webkit-file-upload-button, button {
    padding: 1px 6px;
}
user agent stylesheetinput[type="button" i], input[type="submit" i], input[type="reset" i], input[type="file" i]::-webkit-file-upload-button, button {
    align-items: flex-start;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: default;
    color: buttontext;
    padding: 2px 6px 3px;
    border: 2px outset buttonface;
    border-image-source: initial;
    border-image-slice: initial;
    border-image-width: initial;
    border-image-outset: initial;
    border-image-repeat: initial;
    background-color: buttonface;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheetinput[type="button" i], input[type="submit" i], input[type="reset" i] {
    -webkit-appearance: push-button;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    white-space: pre;
}
user agent stylesheetinput {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    padding: 1px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px inset;
    border-image-source: initial;
    border-image-slice: initial;
    border-image-width: initial;
    border-image-outset: initial;
    border-image-repeat: initial;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    cursor: auto;
}
user agent stylesheetinput, textarea, keygen, select, button {
    margin: 0em;
    font: 13.3333px Arial;
    text-rendering: auto;
    color: initial;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: start;
}
user agent stylesheetinput, textarea, keygen, select, button, meter, progress {
    -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
}
Inherited from div.ap-a-cells.clearfix
localhost/media="all"
#anspress .ap-a-cells {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-left: 70px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
Inherited from div#anspress
localhost/media="all"
#anspress {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, "Segoe UI", Arial, freesans, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background: #fff;
}
Pseudo ::before element
localhost/media="all"
#anspress *, #anspress *:before, #anspress *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
Pseudo ::after element
localhost/media="all"
#anspress *, #anspress *:before, #anspress *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
```

Answer (score 1):

If that is your CSS stylesheet, you don't need to have the `style` tags in it, it's not an HTML file. That could be causing a lot of problems with other CSS files, depending on the order they load.

Comment: Removed the tags, but it still looks messed up. Might there be a tool in the browser's developer tools that could help me see what's going on?

Comment: Sure, try with Element Inspector, see if old CSS is applied to some of the main elements.

Comment: I edited the question to add what I found. I'm not really sure what most of that stuff is. The `#fd_question_submit_button` is mine. Further down it looks like it might be from another plugin. I don't understand - another author's plugin can modify a button I make and modify in **MY** plugin???

Comment: It does look like the original stylesheet is not loading. Check its path on the rendered HTML source, it might not even be there, or in other directory. In the worst-case scenario, you can copy the original stylesheet to your child stylesheet and work from there.

Comment: http://imgur.com/FGyhj54 - This is a screenshot of the source. The only reference to the twentythirteen stylesheet is for the CHILD stylesheet. Should there be 2 references for it? Or is it all a bit more complicated than that...?

Comment: That's the problem then. Copy the sheet to your child theme and build it up from there.

Comment: But then wouldn't that kind of negate the whole idea of a child theme? I thought the idea was that it checks if the styling for an element is present in the child theme, if not, it picks the corresponding styling from the parent theme.

Comment: All of the tutorials I've read walk you through a simple example of setting up the child theme and making a blank style.css to put in the correct folder. when the page is reloaded, a point is made that *nothing* changed. So a blank child-stylesheet means that it will still take all of the parent styling and only add/change what's in the child stylesheet.